# How to avoid a div jumping with position: absolute / fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with `position:fixed`. I've attached a class to this element and want to change its position but it's jumping from top to bottom and the transition doesn't work. Why does this happen?

I attach `.blazon--bottom` class to the element and then `.is-active`

```
.blazon {
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.blazon--bottom {
  bottom: -105px;
  top: auto;
}

.blazon--bottom.is-active {
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
Plugin.prototype.show = function(){
   var that = this;
   $(that.element).addClass('is-active');

   if(this.options.autoClose){
        setTimeout(function(){
            that.hide();
        }, this.options.during);
   }
}

Plugin.prototype.hide = function(){
    $(this.element).removeClass('is-active');
}
```

Full example: [click here](http://codepen.io/lifetowin/full/qamvpA/)

Comment: Your link only points to your codepen profile. Which example is it?

Comment: @CBroe Oh sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: You specified `transition`for the wrong element/class. You have it set for `.blazon`, but the element that you are changing `bottom` on is not that element, but a descendant of it.

Comment: @CBroe If I set `transition` for  `.blazon--bottom` it's still not working.